# How to add an alias domain to Disqus?

Tags: javascript, comments, blogs, jekyll, disqus

I have two sites:

One is `xxx.ruhoh.com` and the other is `blog.xxx.com`. Actually they're the same sites, the only different is the domain name. I embebed the code of `disqus` into the page. However, their comment system can't be shared. For example, if I write a comment at `xxx.ruhoh.com/post1`, this comment can't be seen at `blog.xxx.com/post1`.

Does anyone have ideas about how to merge/share the comment system in two domains for disqus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially what you're trying to do is load a single thread on multiple unique URLs. This doesn't work out of the box because Disqus will identify each unique thread by a unique URL.

What you'll need to do is add a common `disqus_identifier` and/or `disqus_url` javascript variable to your Disqus code. Identifiers and other javascript variables are described in detail [here](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472099) and [here](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables).

From your example above, you can probably extract `/post1` to use as the identifier between the two subdomains. We do recommend setting a `disqus_url`, even if you use an identifier, because one URL is still used as the link-to URL for notifications, widgets, etc. So you'll have to choose one subdomain that you prefer we link to, and make sure it's set on both versions of the blog post.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a `.io` and `.com` domain name and don't want to have to forward one to the other. Setting a variable makes it a lot easier, thanks!